# How to update a table in SQL Server during runtime using bind variable with a placeholder like '?' in python using pyodbc module?

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I am writing a function which would save the records updated in the GUI which is made using Tkinter

```
def save():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=XXXXXXX;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

After connecting to the server,`I am getting values from another function, and updating into my database here,but I am getting an error.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

record_id = select_box.get()

cursor.execute("UPDATE homeaddresses SET (?,?,?,?,?,?) where id=id)",

f_name_editor.get(),
l_name_editor.get(),
address_editor.get(),
city_editor.get(),
state_editor.get(),
pincode_editor.get())

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE homeaddresses SET f_name=?,l_name,address=?,city=?,state=?,pincode=? where id=?",

f_name_editor.get(),
l_name_editor.get(),
address_editor.get(),
city_editor.get(),
state_editor.get(),
pincode_editor.get(),
record_id )
```

Comment: It's working, there was a little typo, both l-name, and address are different, but your answer helped me finding the solution.